# Eliminate use of typedef in a linked list program

Tags: c, typedef

I am studying linked lists and (among other, simpler implementations) I encountered this example:

```
typedef struct ListNode_tag {
   int data;
   struct ListNode_tag * next;
} ListNode;
/* linked list */
typedef ListNode * slist;


void slistInsert (slist * lp, int t)
{
    ListNode * n = (ListNode *) malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    n->data = t;
    n->next = *lp;
    *lp = n;
}

void slistPrint (slist l)
{
    while (l != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", l->data);
        l = l->next;}
}

int main ()
{
    slist l = NULL;
    slistInsert(&l, 13);
    slistInsert(&l, 42);
    slistPrint(l); //print 42 13
    return 0;
}
```

...which seems to work ok, but if I had to **eliminate the use of typedef** I cannot understand which changes I should make. I have tried some solutions but they didn't work.

Comment: You might want to consider giving slist a better name such as typedef ListNode * pListNode, it would make the rest of the code easier to read, since it's clearer that it's a pointer, or don't create a typedef for pointer to ListNode, and just delcare parameters as ListNode * or ListNode ** .

Comment: Why - is those characters so difficult to type?

Comment: It is a good move to get rid of the pointer typedefs.  Replace all occurrences of the typedef identifiers with the corresponding type.  Since you do not define multiple variables on the same line, it is very simple.

Comment: Also do not use `l` (ell) as an identifier, it is visually confusing as it is hard to distinguish from `1` (one).  Some fonts use the exact same glyph for both.

Comment: this code leaks memory. suggest free'ing the allocated memory before exiting main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the program without typedef(s).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ListNode {
   int data;
   struct ListNode * next;
};
/* linked list */


void slistInsert (struct ListNode **lp, int t)
{
    struct ListNode * n = (struct ListNode *) malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    n->data = t;
    n->next = *lp;
    *lp = n;
}

void slistPrint (struct ListNode *l)
{
    while (l != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", l->data);
        l = l->next;}
}

int main ()
{
    struct ListNode *l = NULL;
    slistInsert(&l, 13);
    slistInsert(&l, 42);
    slistPrint(l); //print 42 13
    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that you need also to write a function that will free all allocated memory for the list.

Comment: in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() and always check the returned value (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: @user3629249 First of all it is not my code. I simply have removed typedefs from the original code. And secondly do not repeat stupidy after other low-qualified programmers about not using casting with malloc. And please do not show here a reference for the answer in this forum where this stupidy was upvoted. I already down-voted it.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the answer, I now understand that had trouble figuring out that slist is in fact a fast way to create a ListNode pointer...

Answer (score 1):

typedefs are like simple naming for a complex declaration.

It is easy to write `slist` instead of `struct ListNode_tag *`

Replace all occurrences of `ListNode` with `struct ListNode_tag`. And `slist` with `struct ListNode_tag *`

And your structure will look like this

```
struct ListNode_tag {
   int data;
   struct ListNode_tag * next;
};
```

`slistInsert()` declaration looks like this

```
void slistInsert (struct ListNode_tag **lp, int t)
```

`slistPrint()` declaration looks like this

```
void slistPrint (struct ListNode_tag * l)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `typedef` is just an alias, a different name for something that already exists.  So `typedef ListNode * slist;` creates an alias `slist` for `ListNode*`.  Since `sList` is the same as `ListNode*` just replace `slist` with `ListNode*`.

The other typedef, `typedef struct ListNode_tag {...} ListNode;` creates an alias `ListNode` for `struct ListNode_tag`.  So replace `ListNode` with `struct ListNode_tag`.  In C the keyword `struct` has to be included with the struct's name.